# Spring Security - Get username while logout

Tags: spring-security, logout

How to get username or `UserDetail` object in `logout-success-url`? Below is my configuration:

```xml
<form-login default-target-url="/security/loginSuccess.action" 
            always-use-default-target="false" 
            authentication-failure-url="/security/loginFailed.action"
            login-page="/security/restrictUser.action"/>    

<logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/security/logoutUser.action" />

<session-management 
  session-authentication-strategy-ref="customMsgAwareConcurrentSessionControlStartegy" 
  invalid-session-url="/security/logoutUser.action"/>
```

I want to get the username who has requested for logout within `logout-success-url` (for me it is a Struts 2 action method). I have checked `SecurityContextHolder`, but it seems that `SecurityContextHolder` is cleared when the control reaches my action method in `logout-success-url`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use custom `LogoutSuccessHandler` for that. Inside your configuration define bean and use `success-handler-ref` attribute of `<logout>` tag.

```xml
<logout success-handler-ref="customLogoutSuccessHandler" />
<beans:bean id="customLogoutSuccessHandler" class="..." />
```

And inside `CustomLogoutSuccessHandler` there is `onLogoutSuccess` method which has `Authentication` argument.

```java
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler extends
    AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler implements
    LogoutSuccessHandler {

    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
         // use authentication to get user name
    }
}
```

Comment: why not go the full monty and add `String username = authentication.getName();` to the `onLogoutSuccess` method body?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as I have given logout-success-url, I can not mention success-handler-ref. If I provide success-handler-ref, then how can I redirect the user to my custom page after logout..because onLogoutSuccess method returns void? Secondly, do you mean that Authentication object is available in LogoutSuccessHandler but it will not available to the logout-success-url (though it is a action method and I am trying to access it with SecurityContextHolder) ?

Comment: For your first problem: that why `CustomLogoutSuccessHandler` extends `AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler`, see source code of it. For the second: just try and see for yourself.